# Can't deserialize current json object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to call an api endpoint that contains a list of images based on a query string. So, if I'm looking for cat photos, I pass that parameter, api key and I can get back cat pictures.

The api endpoint I'm using is: 
https://pixabay.com/api/

Here's a sample response for that api:

```
{
"total": 4692,
"totalHits": 500,
"hits": [
    {
        "id": 195893,
        "pageURL": "https://pixabay.com/en/blossom-bloom-flower-195893/",
        "type": "photo",
        "tags": "blossom, bloom, flower",
        "previewURL": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/15/09/12/flower-195893_150.jpg"
        "previewWidth": 150,
        "previewHeight": 84,
        "webformatURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/35bbf209e13e39d2_640.jpg",
        "webformatWidth": 640,
        "webformatHeight": 360,
        "largeImageURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a99fd0a76647_1280.jpg",
        "fullHDURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a9369fd0a76647_1920.jpg",
        "imageURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a9364a9fd0a76647.jpg",
        "imageWidth": 4000,
        "imageHeight": 2250,
        "imageSize": 4731420,
        "views": 7671,
        "downloads": 6439,
        "favorites": 1,
        "likes": 5,
        "comments": 2,
        "user_id": 48777,
        "user": "Josch13",
        "userImageURL": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/user/2013/11/05/02-10-23-764_250x250.jpg",
    },
    {
        "id": 73424,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
}
```

Here's the api call I set up:

```
 public async Task<List<Image>> GetCatImages()
        {
            string query = "cats";
            return await Get<List<Image>>(_baseUrl + $"?key={apiKey}&q={query}&image_type=photo");
        }
```

Here's the get method:

```
protected async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = GetClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The main issue I'm having is: The get method is broken I think. I can't properly deserialize the JSON and I'm not sure what I did above is wrong. My code breaks after setting the obj (The deserialization part). What am I doing wrong?

Here's the exception details:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Image]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'totalHits', line 1, position 13.
```

Comment: *My code breaks after setting the obj* - what do you mean? Do you get an exception? Which one?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma sorry you're right! I do get an exception. See above in edited post

Comment: Your Json is **not** a `List<Image>`, is just a single `Image` object.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma good catch, and right on the money, add an answer and ill upvote and close mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize your Json as a `List<Image>`, but your Json is really just a single `Image` object (wich internally contains a list).

Change your call to the following one:

```
await Get<Image>(yourUri)
```

Comment: Idk why but when I made that change my app just freezes and the debugger stopped. I get: Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application. Do you recommend a better approach for using HttpClient than what I have above?

Comment: I can't tell you more without knowing the context of your call `GetCatImages`